# Issues with latest JRE (7u7) and latest Tomcat (7.0.30) when using 64 bit versions?

Tags: tomcat, java, jvisualvm

I wanted to install the standalone version of Tomcat on Windows 7 in order to profile a web app with jvisualvm (the service version can only be profiled with jmx and this has some limitations). I used the opportunity to try out the 64 bit versions of the JRE and Tomcat, but this didn't go very well.

Tomcat was not starting and it wouldn't go as far as to create a log file. The new console window where Tomcat actually runs after running *startup.bat* was closed almost immediately so I couldn't see what error it was showing. I tried a lot of tricks that I found online in order to show this output on the first command prompt, but they seem to have been for older versions because I didn't manage to make any of them work.

I uninstalled everything and then installed the 32 bit versions using the same steps and now it's working. Is there a known issue with this combination (JRE 64 with Tomcat 7 64)? Has anyone had similar problems with these versions? Thanks.